# symfony2: documentation generated by NelmioApiDocBundle shows an additional route

Tags: php, symfony, routes, fosrestbundle

I'm using [NelmioApiDocBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) and [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/) to create an API.

In my **routing.yml** I have set `prefix` to  `/api`.

The routes in my `ApiController` class are configured as follows:

```
/**
* @Get("/login/{username}/{password}")
* @ApiDoc(
*   description="User Loggin",
*   resource=true,
*   parameters={
*     {"name"="username", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="Username"},
*     {"name"="password", "dataType"="string", "required"=true, "description"="Password"},
*   }
* )
*/
public function loginAction($username, $password)
{
   // ...
}
```

My problem is that the generated documentation shows these **two** routes:

- `/api/login/{username}/{password}`
- `/login/{username}/{password}`

I only want the route prefixed with `/api` to show up.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `NelmioApiDocBundle` isn't aware of the `prefix` setting in your **routing.yml**.

As the bundle usually expects annotations you should add the **[`@Prefix`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/annotations-reference.md#route-prefix)** annotation at class-level instead.

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Prefix;

/**
 * @Prefix("/api")
 */
class ApiController
```

Don't forget to clear your cache after implementing the changes.

Comment: No effect ;) But i found a solution, i override the template and check manually if the uri contains /api or not

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, i override the template `resources.html.twig` of NelmioBundle and check manually if the uri contains /api or not

Comment: That's a pretty dirty workaround - not really a solution. NelmioApiDocBundle is definitely able to handle route-prefixes from my personal experience.